# Ktor Route level plugin intercepting all calls

Tags: ktor

I've written a small plugin to respond 403 to requests that don't have a userId field in JWT token

```
class LoggedInUserAuthConfiguration(
)

val LoggedInUserAuthPlugin =
    createRouteScopedPlugin(name = "LoggedInUserAuthPlugin", ::LoggedInUserAuthConfiguration) {
        with(pluginConfig) {
            on(AuthenticationChecked) { call ->
                call.principal<JWTPrincipal>()?.let {
                    call.userId ?: call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                } ?: call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            }
        }
    }
```

I've written 2 functions to use this plugin but none of them work only on route level

```
fun Route.withLoggedInUser(build: suspend PipelineContext<Unit, ApplicationCall>.() -> Unit) {
    install(LoggedInUserAuthPlugin) {}
    handle { build() }
}

fun Route.authenticateLoggedInUser(build: suspend Route.() -> Unit) {
    install(LoggedInUserAuthPlugin) {}
    handle { this@authenticateLoggedInUser.build() }
}
```

I'm using them like this

```
fun Route.addRoute() {
    authenticateLoggedInUser {
        route("/endpoint") {
            post {
                ...
            }
            get {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}

OR


fun Route.addRoute() {
        route("/endpoint") {
            method(HttpMethod.Post) {
                withLoggedInUser {
                    ...
                }
            }
            method(HttpMethod.Get) {
                withLoggedInUser {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This is working OK for the required route, but other routes are being intercepted by this plugin too

I've checked that installIntoRoute() is being called in ktor source

```
    if (this is Route && plugin is BaseRouteScopedPlugin) {
        return installIntoRoute(plugin, configure)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the `authenticateLoggedInUser` definition is incorrect because you build a route (its children) in a handler. The `build` function must be called only once while routing is being built. The `handler` is called each time a matching request is made.

```
fun Route.authenticateLoggedInUser(build: Route.() -> Unit) {
    install(LoggedInUserAuthPlugin) {}
    build()
}
```

Secondly, in your first use case of the `authenticateLoggedInUser` inside the `Route.addRoute` method, the plugin is installed into a route where this method is called. Here is an example where your plugin affects the `/another` route:

```
authenticate("auth-jwt") {
    addRoute()

    get("/another") {
        call.respondText { "OK" }
    }
}

// ...

fun Route.addRoute() {
    authenticateLoggedInUser {
        route("/endpoint") {
            post {
                call.respondText { "post" }
            }
            get {
                call.respondText { "get" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To solve this problem, install your plugin into individual routes or the `/endpoint` route:

```
fun Route.addRoute() {
    route("/endpoint") {
        authenticateLoggedInUser {
            post {
                call.respondText { "post" }
            }
            get {
                call.respondText { "get" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood the mistake in 2nd approach, but is the approach 'withLoggedInUser' a valid one?

Comment: It's valid if you fix the definition of the `Route.withLoggedInUser` method since it has a similar problem as `Route.authenticateLoggedInUser`.